# Posix Thread Class and Start Routines (pthread)

Tags: c++, class, static, pthreads

I would like to implement a thread class using pthread.
Of course I would like to have different starting routines for each thread I'm creating.
pthread_create tho allows only a static function as starting routine, so it can't be instantiated.
Is there a way to allow that or is it better to use a struct to handle my threads ?
This is the code I wrote sofar:

```
class thread {

    string name;
    pthread_t id;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

public:
    thread (string t_name);

static void* start(void*);

int id_get();


private:

};

thread::thread (string t_name)
{

  name = t_name;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  int stacksize = sizeof(double) * TH_STACK_SIZE * 30;
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stacksize);
  int rc = pthread_create (&id, &attr, &start, NULL);

  cout << "return_code: " << rc << endl;
  cout << id;


}
void* thread::start(void*)
    {
while(1){
cout << "here";
pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    }

int thread::id_get()
{
    return id;

}
```

and my test main:

```
int main(void) {
    cout << "Creating threads" << endl;
    thread test1("first");
    thread test2("second");

    pthread_join(test1.id_get(),NULL);
    pthread_join(test2.id_get(),NULL);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the existing std::thread?

Comment: Cause I'm crosscompiling for ARM and looks like pthread is much more portable (at least it's what I read about).

Comment: What do you thing the std stands for?

Comment: Stay with the `static` thread proc. in the last parameter of `pthread_create` pass a pointer to your `struct`.  The the `static` thread proc casts the parameter back to it's original type and does `pstruct->private_run();`  PS don't create a class called `thread` for these sort of discussions as it is very hard to disambiguate (std::thread and other thread related things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have different starting routines for each thread I'm
>   creating.

Back when I used posix thread, (I now use std::thread), I used a 'two-step' entry mechanism.  At the (small) cost of these two steps, every class could easily have its own thread.

I always keep these entry methods private.

```
class Foo_t
{

   // ... etc

private:
   static void* threadEntry(void* ptr);

   void* threadEntry2(void); // thread actions in an object method

   // ... etc
}
```

Because these are private, the class has some public method to create the posix thread, typically something like:

```
void Foo_t::startApp() 
{
   // ... etc

   int pcStat = m_Thread.create(Foo_t::threadEntry, this);
   //   this 2 parameter method of my thread wrapper class 
   //   invoked the 4 parameter "::pthread_create(...)". 
   //   The 'this' param is passed into the 4th parameter, called arg.
   dtbAssert(0 == pcStat)(m_nodeId)(pcStat)(errno);

   // ...
}
```

Note the second parameter, 'this', to m_Thread.create().

The thread would start in the static method:

```
void* Foo_t::threadEntry(void* a_ptr)
{
  dtbAssert(a_ptr != 0);

  Foo_t* a_foo = static_cast<Foo_t*>(a_ptr);

  void* retVal = a_foo->threadEntry2();

  return(retVal);
```

}

Here, the void* parameter is filled in with the 'this' pointer of the class instance, and then static_cast back to what we need, a Foo_t*.  Remember, this method is private, so only startApp() would create a thread.

Note that threadEntry() invokes an actual method of the class instance called:

```
void* Foo_t::threadEntry2(void)
{
   DBG("Thread %2d (id=%lx): sems %p/%p,  "
       "Entering sem controlled critical region\n", ...);

   // ... start thread work

}
```

And from here, any method of the instance is available.

---

So, what next. There are so many ways to proceed to different thread routines.

Consider adding a parameter to startApp:

```
void Foo_t::startApp(int select);
```

The 'int select' and a switch/case statement could run a unique threadEntry().

Perhaps the 'int select' could be installed (in the instance) so that a later switch/case in threadEntry() could run a unique method or threadEntry2_x().

Or perhaps the switch/case might be installed in threadEntry2().

Consider that the startApp parameter might be a method pointer.

```
void Foo_t::startApp(<method pointer>);
```

The method pointer could be (somewhat more directly) invoked instead of the 'fixed' name threadEntry2().

The above are small issues.

Mutex and having more than 1 thread running in an instance are bigger issues.

I have indeed had multiple threads 'running-around' in a single class instance.  For that I used critical sections, under mutex or some other  guard mechanisms.  std::mutex is convenient, and works with 'Posix' threads, but, on Ubuntu, I often use a Posix Process Semaphore, set to Local mode (unnamed, unshared). PPLSem_t is efficient and fits into 4 one line methods wrapped in a small class.

---

> pthread_create tho allows only a static function as starting routine,
>   so it can't be instantiated.

There is no difficulty instantiating an instance of a class containing a static method.  I'm not sure what you mean in this statement / context.

Review the approach I have detailed above, and you should quickly get to functioning Posix threads in your class instance.

---

Remember to check on stack usage and how much ram is available on your ARM system.  The Ubuntu default stack size is 8 MBytes.  Perhaps your ARM provides stack size control.

Comment: There is a Posix routine to get the stack size  "int stat = pthread_attr_getstacksize(&tattr, &size);"  of the thread in which it is running.

Comment: It occurs to me you might be trying to have a thread create the class instance where it can run.   pthread_create() _can_ invoke a function (i.e. not a  method), and this function does _not_ need to be a static method of some class.  The thread running the function can instantiate the class instance, and jump into the instance via a public method.  Possible.  But I prefer the instance to launch a 'private' thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you have POSIX threads availble, [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) will be available for any C++ compiler supporting the current standard (since c++11).

So basically you don't need to roll your own `thread` class for your cross compiled target (e.g. GCC supports that since version 4.9 or so).

---

But in general your approach is correct. To make it applicable for various classes you can simmply make the `thread` class a template:

```
template<typename T>
class thread {

    string name;
    pthread_t id;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

public:
    thread (string t_name, T& runnable);

    static void* start(void*);

    int id_get();
    T& runnable_;
};
```

And implement the constructor and `start()` function as follows:

```
template<typename T>
thread<T>::thread (string t_name)
: name(t_name)
, runnable_(runnable)
{    
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  int stacksize = sizeof(double) * TH_STACK_SIZE * 30;
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stacksize);
  int rc = pthread_create (&id, &attr, &start, this);
                                            // ^^^^

  cout << "return_code: " << rc << endl;
  cout << id;
}

template<typename T>
void* thread<T>::start(void* pThis) {
    thread<T>* realThis = reinterpret_cast<thread<T>*>(pThis);
    (realThis->runnable)_.start();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The `thread` class can be used then like follows:

```
struct MyRunnable {
    MyRunnable(/* Whatever parameters needed */) 
    : /* Whatever needs to be initialized */ {
    }
    void start() {
         /* Full access to all class member variables */
    }
}

int main() {
     MyRunnable run(/* Whatever parameters needed */);
     thread<MyRunnable> t("TheTreadName",run); // start() will execute here
     // do concurrent stuff
     t.join();
}
```

I just would choose a different name as `thread` to avoid any clashes with the c++ standard library.